# When should I use Message Contracts instead of DataContract and why?

Tags: wcf

Can anyone please tell me when should I use MessageContracts and when should I use
DataContracts and why ?
As I write my wcf service , I always use DataContract but don't know the use of MessageContracts .
Please someone elaborate..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Message Contracts when you need more control. In particular, to specify Headers.

Comment: thanx John , are there any other advantages of Message Contracts over DataContracts ?

Comment: Nothing else, as far as I know.