# Strange change in parameter types in WCF Workflow Service Application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, wcf, workflow

I'll explain what I've done so far. I'm using VS2010.
Firstly I've created a ASP.NET Web Service Application (framewkork 3.5) with a service with these operations:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public Boolean ShoppingTripNeeded(DateTime d)
    {
        DBConnection db = new DBConnection();
        return db.ShoppingTripNeeded(d);
    }


    [WebMethod]
    public String[] ShopsToVisit(DateTime d)
    {
        DBConnection db = new DBConnection();
        return db.ShopsToVisit(d);
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public Item[] ItemsToBuy(DateTime d, String shop) 
    {
        DBConnection db = new DBConnection();
        return db.ItemsToBuy(d, shop);
    }
```

And now I'm creating a WCF Workflow Service Application, in which I want to call sequently the 3 methods above, so I've added a Service Reference to my service wsdl here:

http://awtassignment3-shoppinglistservice1.cloudapp.net/Service1.asmx?WSDL

This referencing adds the 3 operations. The first one "ShoppingTripNeeded" seems to be fine (receiving a DateTime and returning a Boolean), but for the other operations, the parameters have changed in a strange way...

For example the operation ShopsToVisit now ask for a **ShopsToVisitRequestBody** and returns a **ShopsToVisitResponseBody**... I don't know why this happens! because the first operation is fine...

Moreover, as I'm working with a workflow, I can't "play" with this types to find out what's going on...

Have you any guess? any help will be fine...

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you are using ASMX? WCF has replaced Web Services as far more superior service communication technology. See [SO: Web Services — WCF vs. Standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666/web-services-wcf-vs-standard), [SO: Web Service vs WCF Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351334/web-service-vs-wcf-service)

To answer your question:

WF 3.5 will wrap any operation with Request/Response message pattern that is not a primitive (e.g. bool, int). String[] is not a primitive type hence it will be wrapped.

WF 4.0 adding service reference (dialog) will wrap all operations in Request/Response message pair by default regardless if this is primitive or complex type. On top of that, it will create Activity for each operation that it discovers.

Using Request/Response message pattern allows for controlling the message shape specifically message headers.

For Reference:

[SO: When should I use Message Contracts instead of DataContract and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085861/when-should-i-use-message-contracts-instead-of-datacontract-and-why)

[MSDN: Message Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255.aspx)